# Using boost lib within a shared object in Eclipse - undefined reference

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost, shared-objects

I am trying to create a shared object (myLib.so) for a project I am doing. and I have created a separate eclipse 'project' to try and use/test the shared object - they are in the same workspace.

When I compile the project for the shared object (which uses the boost libraries thread etc) everything compiles file and I get no errors.

When I compile the test program and try to link it to myLib.so I get the following errors:

```
/path/lib.so: undefined reference to `boost::thread::interrupt()'
/path/lib.so: undefined reference to `vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
/path/lib.so: undefined reference to     `boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread    _data_base()'
/path/lib.so: undefined reference to `typeinfo for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
/path/lib.so: undefined reference to `boost::thread::start_thread()'
/path/lib.so: undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::ptime const&)'
```

I am unsure if I am compiling myLib.so wrong, or if I have incorrect settings for the test project.  As I say, when I compile myLib.so separately everything seems to work fine but when I compile the test program (which recompiles myLib.so for some reason) it seems to go wrong.

I have myLib.so's source code included in the compiler for the test project, and I have myLib.so included in the linker libraries for the test project.

If anyone could provide some assistance it would be greatly appreciated.  Need any more info please ask.

Thanks,

Extra info:

Make file for the lib.so

```
-include ../makefile.init

RM := rm -rf

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
-include *several-different-files*.mk mostly blank, LIB is blank

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(strip $(C++_DEPS)),)
-include $(C++_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CC_DEPS)),)
-include $(CC_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CPP_DEPS)),)
-include $(CPP_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CXX_DEPS)),)
-include $(CXX_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_UPPER_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_UPPER_DEPS)
endif
endif

-include ../makefile.defs

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 

# All Target
all: libmyLIB.so

# Tool invocations
libmyLIB.so: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C++ Linker'
    g++ -shared -o "libmyLIB.so" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '

# Other Targets
clean:
    -$(RM)       $(OBJS)$(C++_DEPS)$(C_DEPS)$(CC_DEPS)$(LIBRARIES)$(CPP_DEPS)$(CXX_DEPS)$(C_UPPER_DEPS) libPS.so
    -@echo ' '

.PHONY: all clean dependents
.SECONDARY:

-include ../makefile.targets
```

Makefile for the test setup

```
-include ../makefile.init

RM := rm -rf

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
-include sources.mk
-include src/subdir.mk
-include subdir.mk
-include objects.mk

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(strip $(C++_DEPS)),)
-include $(C++_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CC_DEPS)),)
-include $(CC_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CPP_DEPS)),)
-include $(CPP_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CXX_DEPS)),)
-include $(CXX_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_UPPER_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_UPPER_DEPS)
endif
endif

-include ../makefile.defs

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 

# All Target
all: TestingmyLIB

# Tool invocations
TestingmyLIB: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
@echo 'Building target: $@'
@echo 'Invoking: Cross G++ Linker'
g++ -L"/PATH" -o TestingLIB$(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
@echo 'Finished building target: $@'
@echo ' '

# Other Targets
clean:
-$(RM)         $(C++_DEPS)$(OBJS)$(C_DEPS)$(CC_DEPS)$(CPP_DEPS)$(EXECUTABLES)$(CXX_DEPS)$(C_UPPER_DEPS)     TestingLIB
-@echo ' '

.PHONY: all clean dependents
.SECONDARY:

-include ../makefile.targets
```

Also one of the mk files the makefile for the test setup references (objects.mk) contains LIBS := -lmyLIB

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `$(LIBS)`? Sounds like you're forgetting a `-lboost_thread` when you're linking.

Comment: Should that be in the LIBS list for the compiled .so project? Atm that list is blank but it compiles separately without it?? If it needs to be in the test one that would make more sense but I can't seem to add it through eclipse

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error message (related to vtable) often occurs when you compile a projecr with virtual methods unimplemented.

Try to look for every the virtual methods and see if every subclass has an implementation for it.

You can see [this link](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/161894-undefined-reference-vtable#post623595) which is a similar question that has been solved.

Comment: That seemed to be the problem for most of my undefined reference errors, but I corrected all of those and this is what remains...

Comment: Could you paste your makefile (CDT plugin for Eclipse generates a makefile from your project configuration)?

What are the errors remaining? Those you display in your question?

Comment: Please find those above, and yes the errors I put above are the ones left - the ones I fixed were to do with my code/classes, these are with the boost library which is why I believe it could be a linker issue or something similar.